# How to make a fully dynamic prepared statement using mysqli API?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I need to change this query to use a prepared statement. Is it possible?

The query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, content, priority, date, delivery FROM tasks " . $op . " " . $title . " " . $content . " " . $priority . " " . $date . " " . $delivery . " ORDER BY " . $orderField . " " . $order . " " . $pagination . "";
```

Before the query, there's code to check the POST variables and change the content of variables in the query.

```
//For $op makes an INNER JOIN with or without IN clause depending on the content of a $_POST variable
$op = "INNER JOIN ... WHERE opID  IN ('"$.opID."')";
//Or
$op = "INNER JOIN ... ";

//For $title (depends of $op):
$title = "WHERE title LIKE'%".$_POST["title"]."%'";
//Or
$title = "AND title LIKE'%".$_POST["title"]."%'";

//For $content:
$content = "AND content LIKE '%".$_POST["content"]."%'";

//For $priority just a switch:
$priority = "AND priority = DEPENDING_CASE";

//For $date and $delivery another switch 
$d = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["date"]));
$date = "AND date >= '$d' 00:00:00 AND date <= '$d' 23:59:59";
//Or $date = "AND date >= '$d' 00:00:00";
//Or $date = "AND date <= '$d' 23:59:59";

//For $orderField
$orderField = $_POST["column"];

//For $order
$order= $_POST["order"];

//For $pagination 
$pagination = "LIMIT ".$offset.",". $recordsPerPage;
```

How I could do this query using prepared statement?

- The query could be more static but this means to make different prepared statements and execute it depending of $_POST checks.
- It depends on many variables because this query show results in a table that contains search fields and column to order.

A full example of query would be like this (depending of $_POST checks):

```
SELECT id, title, content, priority, date, delivery FROM tasks INNER JOIN op ON task.op = op.opId WHERE op IN (4851,8965,78562) AND title LIKE '%PHT%' AND content LIKE '%%' AND priority = '2' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: That is an extremely dynamically build query. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description what kind of query you are trying to build and why. Why can't the query be more "static" that it doesn't depend on such variable components? Also add example results of queries you want to build to your question.

Comment: You don't have different prepared statements just because you have different values from $_POST.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Just think basically... replace each variable in your current statements with an question mark in your statements. so $v is ?, $x is ?, $test is ? etc. And then bind the value in bindParam(). Please read up on how you do this. You could start with the link I sent in above comment.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I know how to do that. But query needs to be different, like adding or removing IN, >=, <, etc. That's what I need to do

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld to be honest, the task is not that simple, there are many quirks and exceptions. And this particular page doesn't cover even 10% of all possible issues. While promoting certain bad practices, as it always so with w3schools

Comment: @Kirito - my mistake. I didn't look to close at it because too many people just "throws" a question up here and ask how do I do prepared statements without having bind params etc in the code. And then when you typed "I have been searching for it on Google, but it has not been very clear to me" I just moved on to next question. I'll have to learn to not my so negative from now on... But you got a real good answer from someone who has more common sense that I have :-)

Comment: @YourCommonSense - true. Read my other comment :-) I don't think W3Schools is the best in any manner but it's not always bad practice. When it comes it SQL I actually think it's rather good for learning the basics. But in some other areas in programming it's not good at all and even catastrophic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An excellent question. And thank you for moving to prepared statements. It seems that after all those years of struggle, the idea finally is starting to take over.

*Disclaimer: there will be links to my own site because I am helping people with PHP for 20+ years and got an obsession with writing articles about most common issues.*

Yes, it's perfectly possible. Check out my article, [How to create a search filter for mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/search_filter) for the fully functional example.

For the `WHERE` part, all you need is to create two separate arrays - one containing query conditions with placeholders and one containing actual values for these placeholders, i.e:

#### `WHERE` clause

```
$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];

if (!empty($_POST["content"])) {
    $conditions[] = 'content LIKE ?';
    $parameters[] = '%'.$_POST['content ']."%";
}
```

and so on, for all search conditions.

Then you could `implode`  all the conditions using `AND` string as a glue, and get a first-class `WHERE` clause:

```
if ($conditions)
{
    $where .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}
```

The routine is the same for all search conditions, but it will be a bit different for the  `IN()` clause.

#### `IN()` clause

is a bit different as you will need more placeholders and more values to be added:

```
if (!empty($_POST["opID"])) {
    $in  = str_repeat('?,', count($array) - 1) . '?';
    $conditions[] = "opID IN ($in)";
    $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $_POST["opID"]);
}
```

this code will add as many `?` placeholders to the `IN()` clause as many elements in the `$_POST["opID"]` and will add all those values to the `$parameters` array. The explanation can be found in the adjacent article in the same section on my site.

After you are done with `WHERE` clause, you can move to the rest of your query

#### `ORDER BY` clause

You cannot parameterize the order by clause, because field names and SQL keywords cannot be represented by a placeholder. And to tackle with this problem I beg you to use a [whitelisting function](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/order_by) I wrote for this exact purpose. With it you can make your ORDER BY clause 100% safe but perfectly flexible. All you need is to predefine an array with field names allowed in the order by clause:

```
$sortColumns = ["title","content","priority"]; // add your own
```

and then get safe values using this handy function:

```
$orderField = white_list($_POST["column"], $sortColumns, "Invalid column name");
$order = white_list($_POST["order"], ["ASC","DESC"], "Invalid ORDER BY direction");
```

this is a smart function, that covers three different scenarios

- in case no values were provided (i.e. $_POST["column"] is empty) the first value from the white list will be used, so it serves as a default value
- in case a correct value provided, it will be used in the query
- in case an incorrect value is provided, then an error will be thrown.

#### `LIMIT` clause

`LIMIT` values are perfectly parameterized so you can just add them to the `$parameters` array:

```
$limit = "LIMIT ?, ?";
$parameters[] = $offset;
$parameters[] = $recordsPerPage;
```

#### The final assembly

In the end, your query will be something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, content, priority, date, delivery 
        FROM tasks INNER JOIN ... $where ORDER BY `$orderField` $order $limit";
```

And it can be executed using the following code

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($parameters)), ...$parameters);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

where `$data` is a conventional array contains all the rows returned by the query.

Comment: Why does the whitelist function use `array_search` instead of `in_array`. The key is not used. The by ref hack will result in hard to debug code. Instead of pointing out mistakes it magically returns a value. That responsibility should be at the calling side. `$_POST["column"] ?? 'title'`. No magic (why would it use the first one?). No references used which is always good. And more control over the fallback from the caller side. On top of that having to *always* write down the failure message is a sub-optimal API as it looks somewhat clunky to me. And pretty cumbersome at best.

Comment: @PeeHaa ugh, fair points. These solutions are mostly from the legacy without thinking. Looks like Ill implement everything what you said.